# Как реализовать ежедневную отправку сообщений через телеграмм бот через python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, таймер

Хочу чтобы телеграмм бот отправлял **каждый день** в **определенное время** отправлял сообщение пользовательям

это примерный псевдо код

```
if now == '21:00':
    bot.send_message()
```

Answer (score 0):

Для таких задач есть прекрасная библиотека [Schedule](https://tirinox.ru/schedule-cron-python/). Установка: `pip install schedule`

Вот её использование для вашего примера:

```
import schedule, time

def send_messange():
    # ваша функция отправки сообщений
    print("Отправка завершена!")


schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(send_messange)

while True: # этот цикл отсчитывает время. Он обязателен.
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

В ней есть много других вариантов планировки. Как видите, задачи планируются почти на английском языке, так что вы разберётесь